# Point subdomain without changing parent domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

can anyone help me how to solve this problem.
So I bough domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) , what I want to create next is to "point" demo.example.com via ROUTE 53 without touching parent domain DNS ( because parent domain will be hosted on another hosting)
So far I try to create new hosted zone and I add host record (A ) and put public ip address of my instance but nothing happens.Can anyone suggest me what to do  ?

Comment: It might take some time until its ready, you should wait a bit. if you waited enough, i think more details is needed

Comment: @dannymintz8 Hi , thank you for your answer , I try but its still same "This site can’t be reached" On my public IP adress I upload some dummy page but it doesnt work.

Comment: I don't think you do that without changing the parent domain DNS, it needs to be modified and point to route53's nameservers. What you are trying to achieve is DNS delegation. And it makes total sense to need to modify the parent because otherwise what is stopping me from hosting `illegal.example.com` without telling you, or `luk2302.google.com` or `weapons.facebook.com`...